# Obtaining detailed error information from Media file upload process

Tags: uploads

We have an issue with uploading PDF files to websites we build that are created using Adobe Illustrator.  The issue is a new thing (only the last couple of months).  The error description is generic ("unexpected response from the server...") and the result is a 403 access denied response.  We are trying to work out what might have changed to cause the issue and as a first step looking to get some more meaningful information from wordpress as to what the the actual error is.

I am new to wordpress developing, and I have searched for clues on how to drill down into wp to get the information we are looking for but haven't had much luck.  It seems our specific issue is an isolated one.

If anyone knows of any resources online that could help is it would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: have you looked at your PHP error log? A lot of the debugging steps you need to know aren't WordPress debugging steps, they're general PHP debugging steps such as the PHP error logs, and they won't be specific to the media file uploads either

Comment: hi Tom, I checked for error logs and there arent any

Comment: They can be enabled/turned on, without PHP error logs your ability to debug is severely limited, your host may be able to help. It could be that this has nothing to do with PHP and is a permissions or server level error. Either way figuring out how to access or enable error logs should be your number one priority

Comment: Hi Tom.  PHP error logs are enabled but the process does not add anything to the file.  Interestingly, I took a copy of the site and loaded it into Local on my computer and the files that are failing in the live site were uploaded successfully in the local site.

Comment: then it's unlikely to be a PHP based problem, check your HTAccess files and also check the responses in the dev tools in case it's actually security software. Your host may be able to provide Apache/Nginx logs

Comment: OK great, thanks.  I realIy appreciate your response.  I have since checked the raw logs and found the entries that are the 403 response.  the 403 error is the response to the call on async-upload.php.  The file seems to upload 100% of its contents but then fails when the file is put back together again and saved. Many other PDFs and images are uploading without issue so the problem is specific to the 8 or so files I have found so far.